# Show all names found in table when click display button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show all names found in table `#tb` and display as list using jQuery when the user clicks the `display` button.

My code is below. I can add successfully, but how can I take data from column name and show as list?

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>          
        $(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function() {
                var x = $("#txt1").val();
                var y = $("#txt2").val();
                var z = $("#mycountry").val();
                $("#tb").append("<tr> <td>" + x + "</td> <td>" + y + "</td> <td>" + z + "</td><td> <input type='button'class='c' value='Delete'/></td><td> <input type='button' class='d' value='Edit'/></td></tr>");
            });

            $("#tb").on("click", ".c", function () {
                //$(this).parent().parent().remove();
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });

            $("#tb").on("click", ".d", function () {
               var row = $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("editing");
               row.find("td").slice(0, 3).prop("contenteditable", row.hasClass("editing"));
           });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .editing {
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        ID 
        <input type="text" id="txt1" /><br />

        Name 
        <input type="text" id="txt2" /><br />

        Country: 
        <select id="mycountry">
            <option>---select---</option>
            <option>Egypt</option>
            <option>qatar</option>
            <option>saudia</option>
            <option>emarates</option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="button" value="add" id="btn" />
        <input type="button" value="display" id="btndis" />

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Country
                    </td>
                    <td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tb"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/euk6xkzp/

```
$('#btndis').click(function(){
        $('ul').empty();
            $("#tb").find('tr').each(function(i,el){
                var $tds = $(this).find('td');
              //for name
                $('ul').append("<li>"+$tds.eq(1).text()+"</li>");
            }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btndis").click(function() {
    $("body").append("ul");
    for(var i = 1; i <= $("tr > td").length; i++) {
        $("ul").append("li").addClass("li.li-"+i);
        $("li.li-"+i).append($("td:nth-child("+i+")").text());
    }
}
```

**Explanation :**

First, we create the `ul` to store data. Then, we iterate each `tr` child (`td`) with a `for` loop, we create a li and store data into it. It will be displayed in a list, as asked.

Comment: when i implement it give me ul in body are there are any thing wrong in code above

Comment: Yeah, it will implement a ul in the body with all datas

Comment: Can you please edit your answer, so it is having some explanation, or it might be deleted because of the low quality and its content.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```
$("#btndis").on('click',function(){
    $("body").append("<ul id='listNames''></ul>");
    $('#tb td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
       $("#listNames").append("<li>"+$(this).text()+"</li>")
  });
})
```

Please refer code on this Link. https://jsfiddle.net/gq5f5ux2/2/

On click of the display button iterate loop through all the tr>td-second child to get all the names and then append a UL and LI in the body to display list all the names.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class for colum called **"name"** and then you can iterate over  and select the text in the element

```
<td class="name">John</td>
```

Then in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tb').find('tr').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    $('#result').append('<p>'+name+'</p>');
  });
});
```

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/KBfR2arwm9WMXLX7iabe?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

check this [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1gxkwqsd/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  ID
  <input type="text" id="txt1" />
  <br /> Name
  <input type="text" id="txt2" />
  <br /> Country:
  <select id="mycountry">
    <option>---select---</option>
    <option>Egypt</option>
    <option>qatar</option>
    <option>saudia</option>
    <option>emarates</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="add" id="btn" />
  <input type="button" value="display" id="btndis" />

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          ID
        </td>
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>
          Country
        </td>
        <td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tb"></tbody>
  </table>
  <ul id="ulNames">
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var x = $("#txt1").val();
    var y = $("#txt2").val();
    var z = $("#mycountry").val();
    $("#tb").append("<tr> <td>" + x + "</td> <td>" + y + "</td> <td>" + z + "</td><td> <input type='button'class='c' value='Delete'/></td><td> <input type='button' class='d' value='Edit'/></td></tr>");
  });

  $("#tb").on("click", ".c", function() {
    //$(this).parent().parent().remove();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });

  $("#tb").on("click", ".d", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("editing");
    row.find("td").slice(0, 3).prop("contenteditable", row.hasClass("editing"));
  });

  $('#btndis').on('click', function() {
    //gets table
    var oTable = document.getElementById('tb');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {

      //gets cells of current row  
      var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

      // get your cell info here

      var cellVal = oCells.item(1).innerHTML;
      $('#ulNames').append('<li>' + cellVal + '</li>');

    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.editing {
  background: yellow;
}
```